# Need some clarification on getDerivedStateFromProps when reacting to toggling props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the case below, where I need to update the state if some mode was enabled, is there any performance implication of unconditionally copying props.isScaffoldingMode to the state?

I wonder, if I should use didUpdate for this case or copy the prop only when it changes.

I am unsure if getDerivedStateFromProps causes a full re-render, like setting the state in didUpdate would in this case.

Thank you for your time.

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    let newState = { prevIsScaffoldingMode: nextProps.isScaffoldingMode };
   
    if (nextProps.isScaffoldingMode && !prevState.prevIsScaffoldingMode) {
      const scaffoldingState = StandardItemComponent.prepareScaffoldingMode(nextProps);
      newState = { ...newState, ...scaffoldingState };
    }
      return newState;
    }
```

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` do not causes a rerender, but it's called before a render (so, in you case, when props changes).
I would not mind about performance issue, but… are you really sure you need it? `getDerivedStateFromProps` is used in some corner-cases but should be commonly avoided.
Why don't directly use `isScaffoldingMode` prop and forget about storing it in the state?

Comment: @keul It is a legacy codebase. Refactoring it to not use getDerivedStateFromProps would be more costly.